# No value returns from a getting function in c++

Tags: c++, return

I'm facing a problem when using object member from one class in another class, and the GetColor() function called in main prints nothing. It should print out the color attribute of B. Where is my problem? My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B{
private:
    string color;
    int id;
    int val;
public:
    B(){}
    B(int newid, string newcolor){
        cout<<"constructor"<<endl;
        id = newid;
        color = newcolor;
    }
    B(const B & b){
        color = b.color;
        id = b.id;
        val = b.val;
    }

    string GetColor(){return color;}
    void SetVal(int newval){val = newval;}
};
```

class C, which contains object member B:

```
class C{
private:
    B b;
    int num;
public:
    C(int newnum) {num = newnum;}
    void SetB(B newb){
        b = newb;
        b.SetVal(-1);
    }

    B GetB(){return b;}
};
```

class W, which contains a vector of objects C:

```
class W{
private:
    vector <C> c;
public:
    W(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            c.push_back(C(i));
        }
    }
    C CAt(int i){
        return c.at(i);
    }
};

int main(){
W w;
w.CAt(0).SetB(B(1, "red"));
cout << w.CAt(0).GetB().GetColor()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The output is "constructor" followed by a blank newline, the color printed is empty string.

Comment: `B(int newid, string newcolor){` - perhaps `B(int newid, const string & newcolor)` and look yup initialization lists{

Comment: `string GetColor(){return color;}` -> `string GetColor() const {return` color;}

Comment: `C CAt(int i)` This returns a copy of C, so your `SetB()` works on a copy that gets discarded.

Comment: @EdHeal doesn’t change, actually I was using pointer to object before, and address of pointer in SetB is correct, which means it really changed in that scope. But when I want it be returned after setting, the address changes back to unsetted address, in which the attribute was initialized with empty.

Comment: I was commenting on programming style and correct use of `const` - Saves executing a copy. And enables the compiler to optimise better

Comment: @EdHeal  Noted, thx